# get Object array empty after loading canvas Json Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I load object of my canvas with this function

`var objects = canvas.getObjects();`

But when I try to read the array is empty but so weird in the browserconsole appears like this

`Array[0]
0: klass
1: klass
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]`

In my other function to resize canvas the array appears with all the objects I dont why is this happening

Comment: I am sorry, could you provide more relevant code, please?

Comment: I solved it Waiting one second meanwhile fabric is loading objects, when I do getObjects they arent ready to read. I am not sure if this is the best way. But now is solved.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a very similar issue, but it would only manifest when my application was in production. The issue is the objects are not available until the images are loaded, so even waiting one second as one of the comments suggest will not always work.

My solution is to observe for the object to be added to the canvas:

```
 canvas.on('object:added', function(object) {
   // Do something here
 });
```

There is also a related post from a few years ago here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/3RpIRfrJBZ0

Answer (score 1):

I faced such an issue when I was using the `loadFromJSON()` function.

It happens because you call `getObjects()` before all objects are rendered. [loadFromJSON()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) accepts a callback, where you can get all canvas items.

Hope, this will help someone.